# Throttling navigation to prevent the browser from hanging - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`Throttling navigation to prevent the browser from hanging. See https://crbug.com/882238. Command line switch --disable-ipc-flooding-protection can be used to bypass the protection`

This is the full warning it is throwing:

My code:

```
import { login, resetState } from "../../store/auth/authActions";
import { isAuthenticated } from "../../utils/auth";

const Login = ({ history }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  //joi schema
  ....

  //react hook form setup
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    setError,
    clearErrors,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    resolver: joiResolver(schema),
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(resetState(clearErrors));
    if (isAuthenticated) {

      //AS SOON AS I UNCOMMENT THE NEXT LINE THROWS THE WARNING IN LOOP
      // history.push("/dashboard");
    }
  }, [clearErrors, dispatch, history]);

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    dispatch(resetState(clearErrors));
    dispatch(login(data));
  };

  // global state
  const serverSideErrors = useSelector((state) => state.auth.errors);

  useEffect(() => {
    Object.entries(serverSideErrors).forEach(([i, v]) => {
      setError(i, {
        message: v[0],
      });
    });
  }, [serverSideErrors, setError]);

return (...)

export default Login;
```

here, you can see the line :`history.push("/dashboard");`  this is what seems to be causing the issue. If I comment this line. That warning will be gone.

I have also tried with:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(resetState(clearErrors));
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      history.push("/dashboard");
    }
  }, []);
```

but same issue. How, could I fix this? What I am missing here?

Comment: Is there some redirect cycle created between the login and dashboard routes? Can you update your question to include how you are navigating to either of these routes (i.e. the component with `Router` and anything redirecting or linking to these routes)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that `dispatch(resetState(clearErrors));` changes `clearErrors` references. Since `clearErrors` is a dependency of the same hook and it changes in the hook, it gets called in loop, which runs `history.push("/dashboard");` repeatedly.

You should be doing `dispatch(resetState(clearErrors));` conditionally otherwise it'll always end up in loop.

PS: If you could post a minimal repo of this issue, I might be able to help better.